# Having trouble loading ApexCharts using RequireJS

Tags: javascript, requirejs, apexcharts

I'm working with **Tabler ([tabler.io](https://tabler.io))** trying to migrate some of the templates into my own CMS installation. The problem I'm running into is that I'm trying to load all of the scripts using **RequireJS ([requirejs.org](https://requirejs.org/))**, and **ApexCharts ([apexcharts.com](https://apexcharts.com/))** is not loading properly. The relevant parts of my RequireJS config are as follows:

```
requirejs.config({
    shim:{
        'apexcharts':{'exports':'ApexCharts'}
    },
    paths:{
        'apexcharts':'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/apexcharts@3.23.1/dist/apexcharts.amd'
    }
});
```

It is my understanding that by identifying the exports parameter, RequireJS binds the module to the `window` object, but in Dev Tools `window.ApexCharts` is undefined, even though the script shows as being loaded. I've tried both the `apexcharts.min.js` and `apexcharts.amd.js` scripts and no luck with either.

I have code later on in the project that depends on ApexCharts being loaded but it doesn't pass the existence check for ApexCharts. The sample below doesn't completely run because `$(window).ApexCharts` is undefined.

```
requirejs(['jquery','apexcharts'],function($,ApexCharts){
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(window).ApexCharts && (new ApexCharts($('#chart-revenue-bg'), {...})).render();
    });
});
```

The original template from Tabler.io uses the `apexcharts.min.js` script, but as a result of my research into issues with RequireJS, I came across the following Issue reported on Github and tried the `apexcharts.amd.js` script as well as a result:
[**Loading using Require.js (AMD) broken** #357](https://github.com/apexcharts/apexcharts.js/issues/357)

Anyone have insight into what I'm doing wrong here? (I'm not seeing any errors in the console, so I'm stumped)

**CODEPEN example illustrating issue:** https://codepen.io/cjholowatyj/pen/eYBZmrb

Comment: When you use AMD version of ApexCharts you do not need to `shim` it, it will work without it

Answer (score 0):

```
paths:{
        'apexcharts':'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/apexcharts@3.23.1/dist/apexcharts.min',
    'capexcharts':'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/apexcharts@3.23.1/dist/apexcharts.common',
    }
```

and then:

```
define(["capexcharts", "apexcharts"], function (c, ApexCharts) {
       });
```

see this link: https://codepen.io/waleed3amer/pen/GRMNYaQ

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).